# Why does Canvas::GetLeft always return 0?

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, c++-cx

```
<Canvas Background="Black">
        <Rectangle Fill="Salmon" Name="selBox" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="657,175" />
        <Button x:Name="btnAnimate" Content="Animate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="721,422,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="btnAnimate_Click" />
</Canvas>
```

is my XAML. I've written, in the MainPage.xaml.cpp file

```
void App1::MainPage::btnAnimate_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    auto x = Canvas::GetLeft(selBox);   
}
```

When I debug the app, I always get `0.00` for x. Why so? Or is there some translation I've to do with respect to the parent? I also tried naming the Canvas `myCanvas` and did `myCanvas->GetLeft(selBox);` and I still get the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have what you wrote: you didn't set `Canvas.Left` on your `Rectangle` and it is 0 by default. Margin affects the final layout but doesn't affect Canvas.Left or Right or any of other twos.

Comment: Wow, thanks!! Doing `selBox->Margin.Left` gives the right (I mean, correct) value :)